# Running jar from command promt with multiple arguments windows

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

My code is :

```
  public void runSomething(){

    System.out.println(System.getProperty("1"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("2"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("3"));
}
```

I need to run it from command prompt. I am using:

> java -jar jarname.jar -D1=111 -D2=222 -D3=333

Is this wrong way of passing argument values from command prompt as I am not able to print the values?

How to pass the values by key names from command prompt?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove D1,D2 & D3 and try to run run as:

```
java -jar jarname.jar 111 222 333
```

run time arguments are passed to main method as a `String` array as mentioned here:

```
public static void main(String commandLineArgs[])
```

You can fetch the passed arguments using `commandLineArgs` with appropriate index. So in your case:

```
String D1 = commandLineArgs[0];
String D2 = commandLineArgs[1];
String D3 = commandLineArgs[2];
```

Comment: how to get them with some key value.. like System.getProp("KEYNAME")

Comment: Then try to fetch the property without 'D', System.getProp("1"), System.getProp("2"), System.getProp("3")

Comment: is the scope of these variables only till main method class or the child class can access it as well?

Comment: Method arguments scope is always limited to the method. You may have to set other class/instance variables using main arguments or pass the main arguments to other methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of passing some thing as  System property to JVM, better way is to pass it as command line parameter

```
java -jar jarname.jar 111 222 333
```

and you can access these from `public static void main(String ar[])`

`ar[]` would be `{"111", "222", "333"}`

---

- [Command Line arguments `Java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

> java -D1="111" -D2="222" -jar jarname.jar